# How to integrate InsiteCommerce with Sitecore 8.1?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ecommerce

I am trying to integrate Insite Commerce with Sitecore 8.1. I have setup the basic Insite commerce demo site with sample data but I need to integrate this with the Sitecore website.

How can I achieve this? Also where can I download the InsiteCommerce-Sitecore Connector?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this press release: http://www.insitesoft.com/press-releases/new-sitecore-connector-supercharge-integration-content-and-commerce-b2b-digital-initiatives/ they've built a connector that integrates with Sitecore. Searching the internet seems the connector is not avaailable for public download but they provide a contact person for "Insite Software".

I suggest you drop an email to this below contact for further details on how to download the connector.

**Kelly Poffenberger**/Lutz PR (for Insite Software)
714-553-9071
kelly@lutzpr.com

Some useful slides on how to integrate InsiteCommerce with Sitecore can be found here:
http://www.slideshare.net/kautilyaprasad/lasug-insite-plus-sitecore-connector

Regards

Comment: Yes I did contact them which helped me with the installation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only cart that is publicly available is the NOP Commerce connector. The one for Insight is only available from Insight.

Here is the NOP connector.
https://github.com/Sitecore/Commerce-Connect-StarterKit

Answer (score 1):

You will need to contact Insite directly at Kelly indicated. A license for the Insite Plus Sitecore Connector will need to be purchased from Insite if you want to use Sitecore CommerceConnnect and be able to leverage that integration framework. I believe you will need InsiteCommerce 4.1 or 4.2 for Sitecore 8.1. Otherwise, you will need to integrate directly to Sitecore using Insite's REST APIs. Feel free to reach out to me if you have more questions.

Dale

Dtraxler@agencyoasis.com